# null values vs "empty" singleton for optional fields

Tags: scala, singleton, design, null

First of all I'm developing a parser for an XML-based format for 3D graphics called XGL.
But this question can be applied to any situation when you have fields in your class that are optional i.e. the value of this field can be missing.

As I was taking a Scala course on coursera there was an interesting pattern when you create an abstract class with all the methods you need and then create a normal fully functional subclass and an "empty" singleton subclass that always returns `false` for `isEmpty` method and throws exceptions for the other ones.

So my question is: is it better to just assign `null` if the optional field's value is missing or make a hierarchy described above and assign it an empty singleton implementation?

Comment: You're referring to the Null Object Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also attended the same Scala course and I agree with e-i-s that you should use the `Option[T]` type for implementing an optional field. Here are some more ideas.

The pattern involving

- a trait with method `isEmpty`
- several classes or objects extending the trait
- a unique object whose method `isEmpty` always returns `true`

is also used to implement sequence-like immutable structures such as lists, streams, and so on.

Compare:

1. An `Option[T]` type containing the values `Some(t)`, for each value `t` in `T`, and the additional value `None`.
2. A `List[T]` type containing objects built from two subclasses (and their respective constructors) `Cons[T](h: T, t: List[T])` and `Nil`: these represent immutable lists whose elements have type `T`. Note that here the method `Nil.isEmpty` returns true.

`None` indicates the absence of a value, while `Nil` indicates an empty list.

So an optional value `None` is **not** the same as an empty list `Nil`.

**NOTE**

If you need to test if an optional value is defined or not you can use the `isEmpty` method of the `Option` type, or pattern matching:

```
class MyClass(f: Option[String])
{
  val field = f
}
```

and then, to test if the field of an instance `obj` of `MyClass` is defined:

```
if (obj.field.isEmpty)
{
}
else
{
}
```

or

```
obj.field match
{
  case Some(s) => /* do something with s */
  case None    => /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your implementation is in Scala, it is idiomatic to use the `Option[T]` type.

Comment: Wow, that's really helpful. I'm also using this code from java app. How will java work with `Option[T]`? Should I provide some additional methods? Because with _null_ it's simple: `if (object.field() != null) {...}`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can call Option's `isEmpty` from Java to check if there's any value (the equivalent to `if (object.field() == null) { ... }`). But I haven't tried this.

Comment: Using Option core methods isEmpty()/isDefined() and get() works perfectly fine from Java.

Comment: And you have `Option.option2Iterable`, so you can use `Option`s in enhanced for-loops.